# Biml for CozyRock

Tags: ssis, biml

I tried out the bimlStudio and made a BIML file 
Included was a custom component of Cozyrock tabledifference

But the dtsx that was created was not what that component expected.

It expects

```
<arrayElements>
  <arrayElement datatype="...">
  </arrayElement>
</arrayElements>
```

But the bimlStudio made

```
<inputColumns>
  <inputColumn>
  </inputColumn>
</inputColumns>
```

Question:
- can I make the tag arrayElements in Biml?

- if not, can I output custom tags via some programming
  something like

  <# for each>
      arrayElement
      arrayElement
    <# end>

but how do I insert the custom tags into the dtsx that comes out of the biml?

Comment: What do you mean by custom tags? You can only use the included XML syntax. If you want to loop you need to write C# code inside ur BIML.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you exactly mean, but you can do stuff like this:

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Threading.Tasks" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ assembly name="\\XXXXXXXX\Build\DLL\MetaFrameWork.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="MetaFrameWork"#>
<#@ property name="pDWDatabaseName" type="String" #>
<#@ property name="pDatabaseName" type="String" #>
<#@ property name="pSolutionAreaName" type="String" #>
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<#  
string logConnectionString = "Provider=XXXXX;Server=XXXXXX;Integrated 
Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Utility";
string DWDatabaseName = pDWDatabaseName;
string DatabaseName = pDatabaseName.ToUpper();
string SolutionAreaName = pSolutionAreaName.ToUpper();
string MasterPackageName = "MASTERPACKAGE_LOAD_DIM_" + SolutionAreaName + 
"_FROM_" + DWDatabaseName.ToUpper() + "_TO_" + DatabaseName;
string PackageName;

var metadataSelect = Metaframework.GetDimFullLoad(DatabaseName);
List<string> packagescreated = new List<string>();#>

<Projects>
<PackageProject Name="SSIS_DM_<#=SolutionAreaName #>_Dim">
    <Packages>
        <# foreach (var tables in metadataSelect) {
            PackageName = 
"LOAD_DIM_"+tables.DatabaseName.ToUpper()+"_"+tables.EntityName.ToUpper();
            packagescreated.Add(PackageName);#>
            <Package PackageName="<#=PackageName #>" />
        <#} #>
        <Package PackageName="<#=MasterPackageName #>" />
    </Packages>
</PackageProject>
</Projects>
<Connections>
<Connection Name="UTILITY" ConnectionString="<#=logConnectionString #>" 
CreateInProject="true" />
<#=CallBimlScript("..\\..\\Connections\\ProjectConnections.biml",DatabaseNam
e,SolutionAreaName) #>
<#=CallBimlScript("..\\..\\Connections\\ProjectConnections.biml",DWDatabaseN
ame,SolutionAreaName) #>
</Connections>
<Packages>
<# foreach (var tables in metadataSelect) { 
    PackageName = 
"LOAD_DIM_"+tables.DatabaseName.ToUpper()+"_"+tables.EntityName.ToUpper(); 
#>
<Package Name="<#=PackageName #>" ConstraintMode="Linear">
    <#=CallBimlScript("..\\..\\Log\\StaticVariables.biml", "Log") #>
    <Tasks>
        <Container Name="SEQ  DIM <#=tables.EntityName#>" 
ConstraintMode="Linear">
            <Tasks>
                <#=CallBimlScript("..\\..\\Log\\ETL_ExecutionLogStart.biml", 
PackageName) #>
                <ExecuteSQL Name="SQL TRUNCATE <#=tables.EntityName #>"  
ConnectionName="<#=tables.DatabaseName#>" ResultSet="None"> 
                    <DirectInput>   
                      TRUNCATE TABLE [<#=tables.SchemaTypeName #>].
[<#=tables.EntityName #>]                                       
                    </DirectInput>
                    <Parameters>
                        <Parameter Name="@ExecutionKey" 
VariableName="User.ExecutionKey" DataType="Int32" />
                    </Parameters>
                </ExecuteSQL>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT 
LOAD_DIM_<#=tables.DatabaseName#>_<#=tables.EntityName #>">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource ConnectionName="<#=DWDatabaseName #>" 
Name="OLE_SRC <#=tables.EntityName #>">
                            <DirectInput>                                   
                            <# var columnsmetadata = 
Metaframework.GetInputToDimFullLoad(tables.EntityID); 
                            string columns = string.Join("],[", 
columnsmetadata.Select(c => c.S_ColumnName));

                            string database = 
Metaframework.GetInputToDimFullLoad(tables.EntityID).Select(t => 
t.S_DatabaseName).Distinct().First();

                            string loadtype = 
Metaframework.GetInputToDimFullLoad(tables.EntityID).Select(t => 
t.D_LoadTypeName).Distinct().First();

                             #>
                            <#if(loadtype.ToLower().Equals("t2")) { #>
                            SELECT [<#=columns  #>],[GyldigFra],[GyldigTil],
[ErAktuel] FROM [<#=database #>].[out].[<#=tables.EntityName#>] with 
(nolock)
                                <#}
                                  else {
                                      #>    SELECT [<#=columns  #>] FROM 
[<#=database #>].[out].[<#=tables.EntityName#>] with (nolock)
                                 <# }#>
                            </DirectInput>

                      </OleDbSource>
                        <#=CallBimlScript("..\\..\\Log\\ETL_ExecutionLogDataFlowDerivedColumns.biml") #>
                        <#=CallBimlScript("..\\..\\Log\\ETL_ExecutionLogDataFlowRowCount.biml") #>
                        <OleDbDestination ConnectionName="<#=tables.DatabaseName#>" Name="OLE_DST <#=tables.SchemaTypeName #>_<#=tables.EntityName#>">
                            <ExternalTableOutput Table="<#=tables.SchemaTypeName #>.<#=tables.EntityName #>">                               
                            </ExternalTableOutput>                                  
                        </OleDbDestination>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>                     
                <#=CallBimlScript("..\\..\\Log\\ETL_ExecutionLogEnd.biml") #>
            </Tasks>
        </Container>
    </Tasks>
</Package>
<#} #>
<Package Name="<#=MasterPackageName#>" ConstraintMode="Linear" ProtectionLevel="DontSaveSensitive">
<#=CallBimlScript("..\\..\\Log\\StaticVariables.biml", "Log") #>
<Tasks>
    <#=CallBimlScript("..\\..\\Log\\ETL_ExecutionLogStart.biml", MasterPackageName) #>
    <Container Name="SEQ Run packages in parallel" ConstraintMode="Parallel">
        <Tasks>      
        <# foreach (string package in packagescreated) { #>
             <ExecutePackage Name="EPT_<#=package#>">
                <ExternalProjectPackage Package="<#=package#>.dtsx" ></ExternalProjectPackage>
            </ExecutePackage>
        <# } #>
        </Tasks>
    </Container>
    <#=CallBimlScript("..\\..\\Log\\ETL_ExecutionLogEnd.biml") #>
    </Tasks>
</Package>
</Packages>
</Biml>
```

Comment: I just want to add something like '<arrayElements></arrayElements>' that is something the cozyRock component needs, instead of '<inputColumns>'